# .NET Graphics - creating an ellipse with transparent background

Tags: c#, graphics

The following code will draw an ellipse on an image and fill that ellipse with the Tomato colour

```
string imageWithTransEllipsePathToSaveTo = "~/Images/imageTest.png";
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(sourceImage);

g.FillEllipse(Brushes.Tomato, 50, 50, 200, 200);

sourceImage.Save(Server.MapPath(imageWithTransEllipsePathToSaveTo), ImageFormat.Png);
```

If I change the brush to Transparent it obviously will not show because the ellipse will be transparent and the image underneath will show.

How do I set the 'background' of the ellipse to be transparent so that the image contains a transparent spot?

EDIT:

Sorry for the confusion but like this...
[image]

Comment: I'm afraid this is *very* unclear. Can you add an image so we can see what the finished result should be?

Comment: @egrunin - yes I am being unclear but what I think I am trying to say is to create is a transparent spot on an image with nothing underneath.

Comment: Do you only have access to GDI, or is WPF a possibility?

Comment: @Maupertuis - I was hoping to do this as part of pre-processing of images on a website

Comment: What you want to do is fill a GraphicsPath (assuming GDI) with an image. I'm not sure this is possible.

Comment: @Nicholas I'm not sure there is a native way in GDI to do something like this. I read your other comments and it seems all you need to do is some image manipulation - take an existing image, make parts of the image transparent and then save the resulting image. There might be graphics libraries that do this but I don't know of one off-hand.

Comment: If you want to make a "hole" in an image, what do you want the user to see through that "hole"? The page background? (In which case, if the page background is white, just draw a white ellipse on the image, no?)

Comment: @egrunin the correct approach would be to draw a transparent spot on the image since the page background could be multiple different colors or even an image.

Comment: @egrunin - As a personal project I was trying to create pieces of a puzzle that require transparent shapes to be cut out of images - if that is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my second answer and works with an Image instead of a color brush.  Unfortunately there is no RadialImageBrush (known to me).  I've included code to save the image to the disk, and included `usings` to ensure you import the correct components.  This does use WPF but it should work as part of a library or console app.

```
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
namespace WpfApplication30
{
    class ImageEditor
    {
        public static void processImage(string loc)
        {
            ImageSource ic = new BitmapImage(new Uri(loc, UriKind.Relative));
            ImageBrush brush = new ImageBrush(ic);
            Path p = new Path();
            p.Fill = brush;
            CombinedGeometry cb = new CombinedGeometry();
            cb.GeometryCombineMode = GeometryCombineMode.Exclude;
            EllipseGeometry ellipse = new EllipseGeometry(new Point(50, 50), 5, 5);
            RectangleGeometry rect = new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(new Size(100, 100)));
            cb.Geometry1 = rect;
            cb.Geometry2 = ellipse;
            p.Data = cb;

            Canvas inkCanvas1 = new Canvas();
            inkCanvas1.Children.Add(p);
            inkCanvas1.Height = 96;
            inkCanvas1.Width = 96;

            inkCanvas1.Measure(new Size(96, 96));
            inkCanvas1.Arrange(new Rect(new Size(96, 96)));
            RenderTargetBitmap targetBitmap =
    new RenderTargetBitmap((int)inkCanvas1.ActualWidth,
                           (int)inkCanvas1.ActualHeight,
                           96d, 96d,
                           PixelFormats.Default);
            targetBitmap.Render(inkCanvas1);

            using (System.IO.FileStream outStream = new System.IO.FileStream( loc.Replace(".png","Copy.png"), System.IO.FileMode.Create))
            {
                PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
                encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(targetBitmap));
                encoder.Save(outStream);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the result:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a brush using a semi-transparent color.

You do that with `Color.FromArgb(alpha, r, g, b)`, where `alpha` sets the opacity.

[Example copied from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/at1k42eh.aspx):

```
public void FromArgb1(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics     g = e.Graphics;

    // Transparent red, green, and blue brushes.
    SolidBrush trnsRedBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(120, 255, 0, 0));
    SolidBrush trnsGreenBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(120, 0, 255, 0));
    SolidBrush trnsBlueBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(120, 0, 0, 255));

    // Base and height of the triangle that is used to position the
    // circles. Each vertex of the triangle is at the center of one of the
    // 3 circles. The base is equal to the diameter of the circles.
    float   triBase = 100;
    float   triHeight = (float)Math.Sqrt(3*(triBase*triBase)/4);

    // Coordinates of first circle's bounding rectangle.
    float   x1 = 40;
    float   y1 = 40;

    // Fill 3 over-lapping circles. Each circle is a different color.
    g.FillEllipse(trnsRedBrush, x1, y1, 2*triHeight, 2*triHeight);
    g.FillEllipse(trnsGreenBrush, x1 + triBase/2, y1 + triHeight,
        2*triHeight, 2*triHeight);
    g.FillEllipse(trnsBlueBrush, x1 + triBase, y1, 2*triHeight, 2*triHeight);
}
```

Comment: This will paint 3 overlapping circles but I don't think any with have a "transparent spot".

Comment: I know. You and I interpret the question differently; I have no idea what he really wants.

Comment: @egrunin and @Greg - Greg is correct maybe I have phrased this question wrong (I've been googling away but not received the pointer to a solution) I would really like to just create a a transparent spot with nothing underneath

Comment: So do you want to basically make the image transparent in that one spot?  Meaning you will see whatever (if anything) that's behind the image?

Comment: @climbage - yes I am trying to create a puzzle web app where I can create shapes by making parts of the images transparent

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a RadialGradientBrush:

```
RadialGradientBrush b = new RadialGradientBrush();
b.GradientOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
b.Center = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
b.RadiusX = 0.5;
b.RadiusY = 0.5;
b.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.Transparent,0));
b.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.Transparent,0.25));
b.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.Tomato, 0.25));
g.FillEllipse(b, 50, 50, 200, 200);
```

[image]

Comment: is this part of WPF?  Can I use this as part of pre-processing an image on a website?

Comment: Yes, this is part of WPF.  If you replace your g.FillEllipse() line with my code above, the SourceImage.Save() should save the image to disk so it is ready for uploading to the web.